# How to match a whole tag in regex?

Tags: java, regex

There is an html file that contains `<HR size=6 color=black>`

```
<html>
....
<HR size=6 color=black>
....
<HR size=6 color=black>
....
</html>
```

---

---

I want to get rid of `<HR size=6 color=black>`. I tried

```
 htmlText = htmlText.replaceAll("<(?i)hr size="+"\""+"6"+"\""+" color="+"\""+
 "black"+"\""+">", "<h1>splitLineHere</h1>");
 System.out.println(htmlText);
```

But this does not change anything

Comment: I don't see any `"` in text you want to replace. Anyway instead of regex try using HTML parser.

Comment: Parsing html using regex is not a good approach. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using regex specific code? Why not simply:

```
htmlText .replaceAll("<HR size=6 color=black>", "<h1>splitLineHere</h1>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You even don't need regex. Just use `replace`.

```
String str = "<html>" +             
        "<HR size=6 color=black>" +             
        "<HR size=6 color=black>" +             
        "</html>";

System.out.println(
        str.replace("<HR size=6 color=black>", "<h1>splitLineHere</h1>")
);
```